# Почему я не могу добавить файлы в новый git проект?

Tags: git, gitlab

Прошел регистрацию в *Git lab*, нажал на кнопку нового проекта, ввел нужные команды со страницы с проектом.

После команды `git push -u origin master` я получаю ошибки `error: src refspec master does not match any`.

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://git.cloudteam.pro/"my name"/dates.git'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как это исправить.

Comment: Похоже, что у вас локально нет ветки `master` и Git не понимает, чего вы от него хотите, заливая свою ветку `master` в серверную `master`. И я тоже не понимаю.

Comment: @novichek git branch команда, что показывает? Также интересна команда git status. Покажите, что выводят эти команды.

Answer (score 1):

Смущает строка "my name" в `http://git.cloudteam.pro/"my name"/dates.git`. Это то, что у вас в консоли? Вместо "my name" вам нужно указать ваше имя на гитлабе. Для этого отредактируйте файл `.git/config`

Comment: Не надо вручную редактировать `.git/config`, для этого есть команда `git config`.